# Vue3 Returning ComputedRefImpl on Get from Vuex Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, proxy, vuejs3, lodash

I have a VueX store, set up as so:

```
const state = reactive({
  get account() {
    return accountInfo
  }

})

const getters = {
  getAccountInfo: () => computed(() => state.account())
```

Which is being utilized in my route guard as

```
router.beforeEach(to, from, next) => {
...
  let account = store.getters.getAccountInfo()
  console.log(account)
...
}
```

Which is returning a `ComputedRefImpl`, an issue considering I need to access the variables within the object of `accountInfo` to verify that the account exists.

I've attempted to use `toRaw()` to convert the return, as well as `lodash.cloneDeep`, and other various methods for access deep structured objects (as just attempting to log account.name or whatever returns `undefined`).

What is the way one should approach this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unclear what you're trying to do. Currently it looks like a mistake to use `computed` inside getAccountInfo at least